# Linux always hangs when out of physical memory

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

I'm using `ArchLinux`, with `3.18.6-1` kernel, when a software uses more than physical memory (when total memory used is >`5.8` GB), it always lags, unresponsive, and all that I can do is reset the computer. I have provide big enough `swap` on `/etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

My `vm.swappiness` is `1`, the output of `free -m` command:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7800        3059         688         239        4053        4204
Swap:         10247           0       10247
```

I tried to increase the swappiness to `10`, then run a memory eating program [`munch`.c](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/play.html)
but it always hangs when reach about `4000` MB

What's wrong with my Linux?

Or is there a way to automatically kill the program with hugest RAM usage? (that is likely the most recent running program, that is `valgrind` or my recent test program)

Comment: uh...changing `vm.swappiness` from `0` to `10` is a pretty marginal change. Try using `60` or `70` instead.

Comment: regarding the last part of your question, there are a variety of tunables for the OOM killer. `vm.oom_kill_allocating_task=0` should kill off programs that are consuming a large amount of memory but there's no guarantee it'll be the one consuming the most (probably will be though).

Comment: Since you are using a file as swap, what kind of filesystem are you using in /? It may be a filesystem limit in the size of the files it can use. Why haven't you created a partition for swap?

Comment: I create a swap partition, but too small `2` GB, then I create a swapfile `8` GB, the `/` partition is `ext4`

Answer (score 0):

I have experiment with `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/oom_kill_allocating_task`, but it still lags for a few minutes before actually kill the problematic program. In my testing `earlyoom` is the best for this case, to install it, just type:

```
yaourt --needed --noconfirm -S --force earlyoom
sudo cp /usr/bin/earlyoom /usr/local/bin/
sudo systemctl enable earlyoom
sudo systemctl start earlyoom
```

Now try to compile and run this program again:

```
echo '
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int max = -1;
    int mb = 0;
    char* buffer;
    if(argc > 1) max = atoi(argv[1]);
    while((buffer=malloc(1024*1024)) != NULL && mb != max) {
        memset(buffer,0,1024*1024);
        printf("Allocated %d MB\n", ++mb);
    }
    return 0;
}
' > munch.c && gcc -O2 -o munch munch.c 
./munch
```

It would give an output something like this:

```
Allocated 1 MB
Allocated 2 MB
Allocated 3 MB
...
Allocated 4367 MB
Allocated 4368 MB
Allocated 4369 MB
Killed
```

The program with highest memory usage now killed automatically and your system would be always responsive. To see the real time log of service type `journalctl -f -u earlyoom` it would show something like this:

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2014-11-03 10:54:39 WIB. --
Feb 20 13:25:25 s497 earlyoom[20041]: earlyoom v0.3-15-g528196e
Feb 20 13:25:25 s497 earlyoom[20041]: total:  7800 MiB
Feb 20 13:25:25 s497 earlyoom[20041]: min:     780 MiB
Feb 20 13:25:25 s497 earlyoom[20041]: avail:  4963 MiB
Feb 20 13:33:10 s497 earlyoom[20041]: Out of memory! avail: 519 MiB < min: 780 MiB
Feb 20 13:33:10 s497 earlyoom[20041]: Killing process 24984 (munch)
```

press `Ctrl+C` to close that command.

Comment: Does this really explain why your system is hanging even when you're only using 5.8GB of 7GB?

Comment: no, but at least it stop hanging .___.)/||

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a few of my machines: It was as if Linux did not realize I had added swap.

The solution: Upgrade the kernel from 3.x to 4.x.